# ¿Cómo recorrería hacia abajo esta lista enlazada mediante un método si ya está hacia arriba?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, método

```
public class Persona_1 {
  int edad;
  Persona_1 next;

public void persona(){
    edad=0;
    next=null;
}
public void setnext(Persona_1 _next){
    this.next=_next;
}
public void setedad(int _edad){
    this.edad= _edad;
}

public Persona_1 getnext(){
    return this.next;
}
public int getedad(){
    return this.edad;
}

}





public class listas {

    Persona_1 edad;
    int con;

    public void lista(){

     this.edad=null;
     con++;
    }

     public void almacenar_abajo(int edad1){

     Persona_1 nom =new Persona_1();
     nom.setedad(edad1); 
       if(getcon()>0){


        //¿que aria es este caso? si la quisiera recorrer  hacia abajo
       }else{

       }con++;

    }

    public void almacena_arriba(int _edad){

        Persona_1 nom =new Persona_1();
        nom.setedad(_edad);
       if(getcon()<=0){
           edad=nom;
       }else{

           nom.setnext(edad);
           edad=nom;
       }con++;
    }
    public int getcon(){
       return con;


    }

    public void mostrar(){
        if(getcon()>0){
            Persona_1 nom=edad;

            while(nom!=null){

               System.out.println( nom.getedad());
         nom= nom.getnext();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("no hay datos");
        }
    }

}


package persona;

/**
 *
 * @author Personal
 */
public class Persona {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
      listas listas= new listas();

       listas.almacena_arriba(40);
       listas.almacena_arriba(90);

       listas.mostrar();
    }

}
```

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
      listas listas= new listas();
    
       listas.almacena_arriba(40);
       listas.almacena_arriba(90);
       
       listas.mostrar();
    }                                                                                                          veras si yo llamo a esa clase se imprime 90 y 40 ahora solo quiero que se imprima 40 y 90 osea hacias abajo

Comment: que es abajo?? que es arriba?? de que lista hablas?? no hay ninguna lista ahi.. y cualquier aclaracion agregala en la pregunta. Limita el codigo a la parte que te genera problemas.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Debes agregar todo eso y una descripción en la pregunta, presiona este link para editarla https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/87926/edit Se que quizá estés un poco atareado, pero también te recomiendo que leas [como usar este sitio para preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tal como te lo recomienda gbianchi o tu pregunta puede ser cerrada (y obviamente no será respondida)

Comment: Ay esta todo el código solo quiero una sugerencia para crear un método que permita imprimir el 40 y 90 en ese orden ya que así se esta almacenando hacia arriba es decir primero se imprime el 90 y después el 40.

Comment: en pocas palabras... si no nos ayudas a ayudarte, dificil que podamos hacer algo por vos. se que esta todo el codigo (y lo esta) a simple vista parece que nunca recorres tu clase persona.. que pasa si agregas 3 personas? y arriba y abajo seran de mayor a menor y viceversa?

Comment: El código de la clase listas no tiene un constructor bien definido ni implementa una lista de ningún tipo. Empieza estudiando lo básico de cómo implementar estructuras de datos o utiliza una colección de Java como ArrayList que ya está implementada y funciona bien.